# Socket Exception at FTPClient::retrieveFile

Tags: java, apache-commons-net

I have an application that should connect to a ftp server an download a file. Some months ago, everything worked fine, but now I wanted to change some parts and get exceptions at retrieveFile:

```
FTPClient ftp=ConnectToServer();
OutputStream stream = new FileOutputStream("TempServerLog.txt");
ftp.retrieveFile(FileName, stream);
```

This is the StackTrace:

```
java.net.SocketOutputStream.socketWrite0(Native Method)
java.net.SocketOutputStream.socketWrite(Unknown Source)
java.net.SocketOutputStream.write(Unknown Source)
sun.nio.cs.StreamEncoder.writeBytes(Unknown Source)
sun.nio.cs.StreamEncoder.implFlushBuffer(Unknown Source)
sun.nio.cs.StreamEncoder.implFlush(Unknown Source)
sun.nio.cs.StreamEncoder.flush(Unknown Source)
java.io.OutputStreamWriter.flush(Unknown Source)
java.io.BufferedWriter.flush(Unknown Source)
org.apache.commons.net.ftp.FTP.__send(FTP.java:501)
org.apache.commons.net.ftp.FTP.sendCommand(FTP.java:475)
org.apache.commons.net.ftp.FTP.sendCommand(FTP.java:552)
org.apache.commons.net.ftp.FTP.port(FTP.java:877)
org.apache.commons.net.ftp.FTPClient._openDataConnection_(FTPClient.java:709)
org.apache.commons.net.ftp.FTPClient._retrieveFile(FTPClient.java:1677)
org.apache.commons.net.ftp.FTPClient.retrieveFile(FTPClient.java:1669)
Util.FtpServer.DownloadConfigurationFile(FtpServer.java:83)
Main.main(Main.java:40)
```

The command in sendCommand is "PORT 127,0,0,1,192,226\r\n". I use the FileZilla FTP Server on a Win7 machine. The server runs fine, I can use the FileZilla Client with the same Username/Pw.

The Serverlog tells me:

```
(not logged in) (127.0.0.1)> Connected, sending welcome message...
(not logged in) (127.0.0.1)> 220-FileZilla Server version 0.9.37 beta
(not logged in) (127.0.0.1)> 220 Lokaler Test FTP Server - have fun!
(not logged in) (127.0.0.1)> USER peter
(not logged in) (127.0.0.1)> 331 Password required for peter
(not logged in) (127.0.0.1)> PASS 
peter (127.0.0.1)> 230 Logged on
peter (127.0.0.1)> disconnected.
```

So I can successfully log in, but I get disconnected during the retrieve file.

I have still a compiled jar of the old versions which seams to work with my local server. I also tried updating Apache-Commons-net from 2.2 (which I used, when I started the project) to the current version 3.1 but the error remains the same.

I also checked out an old version from my git repo of the project it has now the same problem. I used an extra Eclipse installation for this project, so the whole environment should not have been changed, but still I get this socket error.

Comment: Can you post the stack trace?

Comment: Also, do you enter passive mode at any point? ftp.enterLocalPassiveMode()

Comment: I added the stack trace. I don't use anything like passive mode, just simple basic functionality.

Comment: I would try to enter passive mode ftp.enterLocalPassiveMode().  If it's still an issue, you may want to try downloading the ftpclient example and see if that will connect.  It's a pretty full example that you can modify and build on.  http://commons.apache.org/net/examples/ftp/FTPClientExample.java

Answer (score 0):

It seams, that the Windows Firewall caused this problem. Also it should have been just active for public Networks it seams that it somehow caused problems when I was connecting to localhost. After deactivating it completely, my program seams to work.